# Granting a non changeable permission to a third party app with root access

Tags: android, root, android-permissions, securityexception, android-securityexception

On my rooted android device, how can I grant "Signature level" (INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW) permission to a third party app.

What I have tried already is 
rooted my device using magisk
in adb shell, used  `pm grant com.example.app android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW`
After this, I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.INTERNAL_SYSTEM_WINDOW requested by com.example.app is not a changeable permission type
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.BasePermission.enforceDeclaredUsedAndRuntimeOrDevelopment(BasePermission.java:429)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:2114)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService.access$900(PermissionManagerService.java:121)
    at com.android.server.pm.permission.PermissionManagerService$PermissionManagerServiceInternalImpl.grantRuntimePermission(PermissionManagerService.java:3018)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.grantRuntimePermission(PackageManagerService.java:5735)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runGrantRevokePermission(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1955)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:230)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:104)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:21745)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:881)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:765)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:4860)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4015)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1021)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:994)
```

Was looking for a way such that I can grant all types of permissions to the app (since I have root access).

Comment: Did you get to know how to do this?

Comment: You can grant this permission via the Android source code by modifying the privapp-permissions-platform.xml and recompiling AOSP with "make update-api && make" command.

Comment: Is it possible to just edit the /etc/permissions/some-permission-file.xml and this permission will be granted?